# How to do maven organizational wide pom management?

Tags: maven, jenkins, parent, pom.xml, nexus

HI I am setting up maven+jenkins+nexus in our project and read pretty much all posts on this topic. I finally decided to use a master POM only project which contains 'distributionManagement' that contains references to nexus release and snapshots references and some common dependencies like log4j, junit which are used by pretty much all projects.

here is my situation. 
I have project A & B. B depends on A (so B pom.xml has dependency to A.jar) both of them has parent tag referring to Master project. when I try to compile project-B using jenkins, I am getting errors saying that it can't resolve dependencies like log4j, junit etc. Jenkins settings.xml has credentials to nexus. and I still haven't deactivated anonymous user on nexus yet.

and second question, is for some reason, my eclipse (I use juno) from my mac can't compile successfully when I over write my user settings.xml with nexus details.

```
<mirrors>
<mirror>
  <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://myorg.nexusserver.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: do you have repositories and pluginRepositories configured in the settings file?

Comment: did you deploy the Master pom in Nexus ?

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is issue with my eclipse cache. Once I closed-reopen+ refresh it started working OK.